# How to send error message from one aspx page to another aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
       Exception ex = this.Server.GetLastError();   
       this.Server.ClearError();    
       string errorMessage = ex.Message;   
       logger.Error(errorMessage, ex);    
       Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
 }
```

Comment: you can use session in asp.net that's the easiest way i can think off

Comment: Try using query string, passing the error code.

Comment: In this case i would prefer the session. Then you can keep the full exception including stacktrace for further processing.

Comment: I want to get error message for example "DB connection failed" and want to show it on a common error page where I can show other error messages  also.

Comment: I am beginner so will you please share any example so that it will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would prefer the session. Then you can keep the full exception including stacktrace for further processing. But you can't access the session directly  in the `Application_Error`. This should work:

```
private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = this.Server.GetLastError();   
    // ...
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;
    context.Session["LastError"] = ex;
    Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
}
```

Now you can access the exception in `Error.aspx` in this way:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = (Exception)Session["LastError"];
}
```

Comment: is there no need to redirect the page ? how can I retrieve the message on another page?

Comment: @ashT: but i have redirected

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Server.Transfer`in `Global.asax`:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
                    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

                    //direct user to error page 
                    Server.Transfer("~/Error_Pages/ErrorPage500.aspx");
  }
```

And in your error page, you can get inner exception to check the actual occured exception:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
                LoadError(Server.GetLastError());
  }

protected void LoadError(Exception objError)
  {
                Exception innerException = null;           
                if (objError != null)
                {
                    if (objError.InnerException != null)
                    {
                        innerException = objError.InnerException;
                    }
                }
 }
```